# Controlling Servo with PCA9685 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pca, servo, thonny

I am trying to control 2 servos from my pca9685 which is connected to my raspberry pi. I have written code that works with key inputs like I want, but I am only able to use one key input, and then I don’t get a response after the first key input. Any idea on how to fix the issue?

```
import time
import adafruit_servokit import ServoKit

kit = ServoKit(channels=8)
key = input()
angle = 0

while angle <= 100:
    if key == "a":
        kit.servo[0].angle = 100
        time.sleep(1)
    elif key = "aa":
        kit.servo[0].angle = 0
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with the key assignment 'a' and 'aa', if you can change the 'aa' with some other key input i guess it will work, because when using the input() stream it processes the stream character by character so "aa" will be an equivalent of 'a' + 'a', hence you are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my key = input() was outside of the while loop. By having it outside of the loop, it was only being called once.

```
import time
import adafruit_servokit import ServoKit

kit = ServoKit(channels=8)
angle = 0

while angle <= 100:
    key = input()
    if key == "a":
        kit.servo[0].angle = 100
        time.sleep(1)
    elif key = "aa":
        kit.servo[0].angle = 0
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is with the key assignment 'a' and 'aa', if you can change the 'aa' with some other key input i guess it will work, because when using the input() stream it processes the stream character by character so "aa" will be an equivalent of 'a' + 'a', hence you are facing this issue

Comment: So tried using key "q" instead of "aa" and I am not getting a response after I turn the servo the first time.

Comment: Can you try logging the angle value and see whats the issue. as maybe the angle might not be in the range <=100 after the other movement which might be causing the q command to be hidden post the a movement.